# Ffmpeg Video frame rate issues

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a 45 mins video with 15 fps. (I refer this information from window's file explorer property section.)
When I used ffprobe to count the frames, I found some bizarre results.

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 input.avi
13426
```

Mathematically speaking, the video frames should be at least 45 mins * 60 sec / 1 min * 15 frames / sec = 40500. But, in reality, this video's fps is rather 13426 frames / (45 mins * 60 sec) ~ 4.97 fps, closer to 5 fps.

If frame rates are not correctly matched to the actual frame numbers in the video, how do I fix this?

`ffmpeg -i input.avi` shows the output below.

```
  ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Duration: 00:45:00.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 789 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 785 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 30 tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Can you show the output from `ffmpeg -i input.avi`?

Comment: @Lex I just edited the original post.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure what's going on here. It seems that the stream has 15 fps but maybe it has some variable framerate, it can also be some `avi`'s special thing. You can try to re-set the frame rate at a stable 15 fps and put the stream into another container (like `mp4`) without re-encoding at the same time. Use `ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -c copy -f h264 input.h264` and then `ffmpeg -y -r 15 -i input.h264 -c copy input.mp4`.

Comment: I ran the code and output comes out as ~15 mins 15 fps video. The actual video length was 45 mins, and I think it compressed the video length. I want the original frame numbers with original video length, but fixed the frame rate to the correct one..

Comment: This confirms the ratio: the detected amount of frames vs the duration  - if the duration goes down 3 times so the original framerate could be 3 times slower as well. What's on this video? Does this new 15 mins version run faster than original one? Or maybe it ends too early?

Comment: You can count actual video frames with `ffmpeg -i <input.avi> -f null /dev/null`. The AVI media container does NOT support H.264 video stream (and/or modern video codecs), it has no frame reordering mechanism for P/B-frame. see also http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?s=&threadid=80430